# sudo mkdir in bash script without password

Tags: sudo, mkdir

I need to manually create a directory using the following command in a `cronjob` and not have to enter in a password:

```
sudo mkdir /fold1/
```

I have read that I should not edit `/etc/sudoers` directly.

What are my options?

Comment: What does your system administrator say about editing /etc/sudoers? Do they prefer to use a file in /etc/sudoers.d/ ?  Do you need to use sudo without changing the existing sudoers privileges?

Comment: Why do you need to use `sudo` inside the cron job? Does your system not support running cron jobs as other users (via `/etc/crontab`, or `sudo crontab -e` for example)?

Comment: Often "I should not edit /etc/sudoers directly" means simply "I have to use the `visudo` command to edit /etc/sudoers". Please check `man visudo`.

Comment: You asked explicitly about cronjob why this is not a direct answer. But you could serialze it via systemd-unit and set the run-user to root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the script to root's `cronjob`:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

You need to be a sudoer to run the above command. You also will still have to `cd` to the correct directory inside your script to create your new directory in the right location.